# TinyMCE as component in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, tinymce

I manged to integrate TinyMCE as EmberJS component which is not a hard job at all. I am thinking of passing the setup parameters of TinyMCE as an array within the template that renders the TinyMCE component. like the following

{{tinymce-editor config="[menu: false]" }}

or something like that in which I pass the whole array to the component which is in it role setups tiny mce like this

```
didInsertElement: function(){
var textarea = "#" + this.get("elementId");
var config= this.get('config');
if( config === undefined){
    config = {
        selector: textarea ,
    }
}
    tinymce.init(config);
```

I can't figure out how to do so. I would appreciate tips on that.

Here is the whole code I wrote

http://jsbin.com/IcEZumU/1/

Best,
Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in an array, pass in a property that is defined on the `IndexController`. I updated your jsbin!

http://jsbin.com/iNIyOge/1/edit